# is it possible to convert from hbase to spark rdd efficiency?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

I have a large dataset of items in hbase that I want to load into a spark rdd for processing.  My understanding is that hbase is optimized for low-latency single item searches on hadoop, so I am wondering if it's possible to efficiently query for 100 million items in hbase (~10Tb in size)?

Comment: see: http://hbase.apache.org/1.1/book.html#spark

Comment: thanks, that looks like a great resource.

Comment: Could you give more details ? What's your cluster like, what sort of query are you talking about (lookup by rowkey or do you have other criteria), are joins needed, ... ?
Some basic tips : use large scans and filter with Spark (if needed), not with the HBase filters, leverage partitioning and colocation.

Comment: It's a simple key join.  If a hbase table was accessible as an rdd then I'd do this: `val data = hbaseTable.keyBy(itemId).join(myRdd).map(_._2._1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some general advice on making Spark and HBase work together.

**Data colocation and partitioning**

Spark avoids shuffling : if your Spark workers and HBase regions are located on the same machines, Spark will create partitions according to regions.
A good region split in HBase will map to a good partitioning in Spark.
If possible, consider working on your rowkeys and region splits.

**Operations in Spark vs operations in HBase**

Rule of thumb : use HBase scans only, and do everything else with Spark.

To avoid shuffling in your Spark operations, you can consider working on your partitions. For example : you can join 2 Spark rdd from HBase scans on their Rowkey or Rowkey prefix without any shuffling.

**Hbase configuration tweeks**

This discussion is a bit old (some configurations are not up to date) but still interesting : http://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/How-to-optimise-Full-Table-Scan-FTS-in-HBase/td-p/97

And the link below has also some leads: 
http://blog.asquareb.com/blog/2015/01/01/configuration-parameters-that-can-influence-hbase-performance/

You might find multiple sources (including the ones above) suggesting to change the scanner cache config, but this holds only with HBase < 1.x

Answer (score 0):

We had this exact question at Splice Machine.  We found the following based on our tests.

1. HBase had performance challenges if you attempted to perform remote scans from spark/mapreduce.
2. The large scans hurt performance of ongoing small scans by forcing garbage collection.
3. There was not a clear resource management dividing line between OLTP and OLAP queries and resources.

We ended up writing a custom reader that reads the HFiles directly from HDFS and performs incremental deltas with the memstore during scans.  With this, Spark could perform quick enough for most OLAP applications.  We also separated the resource management so the OLAP resources were allocated via YARN (On Premise) or Mesos (Cloud) so they would not disturb normal OLTP apps.

I wish you luck on your endeavor.  Splice Machine is open source and you are welcome to checkout out our code and approach.